# What is the difference between using an address of a FILE variable and a FILE * in C?

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

Given the following short example

```
FILE *p = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
FILE f = *p;

int i;
fscanf(p, "%i", &i); // works just fine
fscanf(&f, "%i", &i); // segmentation fault
```

I have read a little about `FILE`, `FILE *` as well as the actual struct type `_IO_FILE`, but it isn't really clear to me what is causing the segmentation fault in the second call to `fscanf`.

So aside from `p` and `&f` containing different addresses and unless this is involved (which I think it is), what is the difference between `&f` and `p` in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C Standard (C99 7.19.3/6, C11 7.21.3/6) says:

> The address of the FILE object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a FILE object need not serve in place of the original.

So you have been warned.

Comment: Got it! Anywhere I can find more information about this? Like the sense behind this having an undefined behavior rather than taking this for granted?

Comment: The C standard and its rationale are good places to look (see [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/83763#83763).  [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/) is another good source.

Comment: As of C11, `FILE` may be an incomplete type, so it might not even be possible to define a `FILE` object. C11 says `FILE` is an "object type"; C11 changed the definition of "object type" to include incomplete types. Note that `fpos_t` is required to be a "complete object type", so the change appears to have been deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `FILE*` as an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) sensu lato, you should never try to do what you are doing.

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c):

> C streams are objects of type `std::FILE` that can only be accessed and manipulated through pointers of type `std::FILE*` **(Note: while it may be possible to create a local object of type `std::FILE` by dereferencing and copying a valid `std::FILE*`, using the address of such copy in the I/O functions is undefined behavior).**

Comment: There is no `std::` in C.